# ¿geolocalizacion no se obtiene?

Tags: javascript

```
    <head> 

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

        <html>

        <body>
    <form>
      Your location:<br>
      <div class="flex">
        <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="address">
        <input type="hidden" name="gps">
        <div class="gps-button-wrap">
          <button class="get-gps">Get location</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <script>

      jQuery(document).ready(function($){

      $(".get-gps").locationField({
        addressFieldName: "address",
        gpsFieldName: "gps",
        gpsButtonWrap: ".gps-button-wrap",
      });

    });

      </script>
    </form>
```

cuando le doy al get location, no obtiene nada simplemente se queda asi vacio, agradezco que me orienten Gracias. no me arroja ningun error.  no se si es por colocar mal el script o si le hace falta algo mas al script

Comment: Hola @Juan, ¿te sirve con JavaScript puro?

Comment: si tambien me sirve, pero lo que quiero obtener no es la latitud o longitud en si , si no el nombre de dicha ubicación